# Incrementing and Decrementing changing object value

Tags: java, object, increment

Can anyone tell me the reason for the change in output.

```
public class Demo {
  public void demo()
  {
        Integer y = 567;
        Integer x = y;
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
        System.out.println(y == x);
        y++;
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
        System.out.println(y == x);
        y--;
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
        System.out.println(y == x);
  }
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
        Demo obj = new Demo();
        obj.demo();
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
567 567

true

567 568

false

567 567

False
```

Here why i'm getting the final false.

Comment: Try y.equals(x) instead of ==.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Integer y = 567; // y=567
    Integer x = y;   // x is equal to y object
    System.out.println(x + " " + y); // out put x and y so obviously x and y are 567
    System.out.println(y == x); // here x and y are in same reference. so this x==y is true and out put is true. 
    y++; // increment y by 1. then y=568
    System.out.println(x + " " + y); // now x= 567 and y= 568
    System.out.println(y == x);// now x not equals to y then false will print
    y--; // again decrement y value
    System.out.println(x + " " + y); // again x and y are same 567
    System.out.println(y == x);// here y.value == x.value but x and y object wise not equal since object x and y are referring deference points
```

Comment: Wrong, the `==` **always** does Object reference check. The explanation to the 2nd `false` is incorrect.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi i mean it. But you get it wrong. now i change some WORDS

Answer (score 5):

You are using `Integer` which is an immutable object.

Basically your code is

```
y = new Integer(y.intValue() + 1);
```

and

```
y = new Integer(y.intValue() - 1);
```

Therefore you're creating two new `Integer` objects that are not the same (`==`) as the previous objects.

This behaviour is called *autoboxing* in Java.

Comment: The compiler will use `Integer.valueOf()` instead of the constructor.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I used the constructor to make it more clearly, not to show what the JVM is doing.

Answer (score 3):

Change your

```
    Integer y = 567;
    Integer x = y;
```

to

```
    int y = 567;
    int x = y;
```

and the suprprising behavior will be gone. My guess is that you have stumbled upon Java's implicit *autoboxing* of primitive values into wrapper objects, and are lead to believe that you are directly manipulating the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the compiler does this internally:

```
y--
```

means:

```
int _y = y.intValue();
_y--;
y = Integer.valueOf(_y);
```

Therefore, `y` is has a new `Integer` instance. You are doing Object reference check (when using `==`) and not value equality check.

Use `equals()` method to evaluate 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

Because x and y are referring to 2 different objects.

```
y--;
```

This first unboxes y to int than decrements it and than boxes it to Integer. And this new boxed integer is referring to a different memory location.

Ideally, on wrapper classes, its better to call equals method on wrapper object rather than == operator.

Answer (score 0):

`y == x` checks for content-equality, that is, whether they pointed to the same object, not whether the object they pointed to contains the same `int`. Especially when `x, y >= 128`.

Use

```
y.equals(x);
```

or

```
(int) y == (int) x
```

or declare `x` and `y` as `int` instead.

Note that auto-unboxing doesn't happen in `Integer == Integer` or `Integer != Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use primitive `int` instead of the `Integer`. The final output would be `true`.

However when you use `Integer` class, these are `Object`s. If you use the `equals` method the final output would be `true`.

Comment: `When you use Integer instead of the primitive int. The final output would be true.`. What?

Answer (score -1):

Even, if you create

```
Integer a = new Integer(1000);
Integer b = new Integer(1000);
```

a==b - false

but for

```
Integer a = new Integer(1);
Integer b = new Integer(1);
```

a==b - is true

In java there is a cache of small integers: -127 to 128. All other integers are newly created objects and they can not be equals.

Comment: In Java `new` operator **always** allocates memory for a new object. That's contrary to the `public static Integer valueOf(int i)` method that takes integers for the range specified in your answer from internal cache, otherwise returning a new integer.